# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when convert to Arabic digits breaks

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert english digits in given string to Arabic digits. that works fine except if the given string (from web service) contains arabic digits rather than english. for that i get the following error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=1586

I am using the following function to do the conversion task:

```
  public static String convertToArabicDigits(String str) {
        char[] arrayOfChar = {1632, 1633, 1634, 1635, 1636, 1637, 1638, 1639, 1640, 1641};
          if ((str != null)|| (!str.isEmpty())) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                    builder.append(arrayOfChar[(int) (str.charAt(i)) - 48]);
                } else {
                    builder.append(str.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
          else return "";
    }
```

this occurs if string contains arabic digits like :

> التقنية الأكثر طلباً التي سيحرم منها العالم العربي في العام ٢٠١٦

but as mentioned if string contains english digits, the conversion function works fine

> التقنية الأكثر طلباً التي سيحرم منها العالم العربي في العام 2016

can you please help?

**EDIT:**
i think i should  skip the conversion if  `(str.charAt(i)))` is  exits in `arrayOfChar`, do conversion otherwise.

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is clear, your index `1586` which generated from `(int) (str.charAt(i)) - 48]` is wrong as index, so you have to change it to be suitable with your array length, but this problem is because the condition `Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)` it will return true if the char is Arabic or English digit.

So you have to change this condition from:

`if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {`

To:

`if (isContains(englishDigits, str.charAt(i))) {`

And add the following line near your arrayOfChar:

`char[] englishDigits= {48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57};`

So even you pass string like 34٣٤٥ the method will return ٣٤٣٤٥

isContains is method to check if the char is in the char array.

//EDIT

```
public static boolean isContains (char[] arr, char c) {
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it is better to use some library to do it like commons.apache [ArrayUtils.contains](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#contains%28char[],%20char%29)

//EDIT 2

I think it is better to convert without using arrays by replacing these lines:

```
if (isContains(englishDigits, str.charAt(i))) {
builder.append(arrayOfChar[(int) (str.charAt(i)) - 48]);
```

With:

```
if (str.charAt(i)>=48 && str.charAt(i)<=48+9) { // english digit
builder.append((char)(str.charAt(i)-48+1632)); // convert from english to arabic digit
```

Comment: can you please provide the isContains method

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work at all. i.e. digits remains in english and not converted to arabic :)